# sql select into subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm doing a data conversion between systems and have prepared a select statement that identifies the necessary rows to pull from `table1` and joins to `table2` to display a pair of supporting columns. This select statement also places blank columns into the result in order to format the result for the upload to the destination system.

Beyond this query, I will also need to update some column values which I'd like to do in a separate statement operation in a new table. Therefore, I'm interested in running the above select statement as a subquery inside a `SELECT INTO` that will essentially plop the results into a staging table.

```
SELECT 
    dbo_tblPatCountryApplication.AppId, '', 
    dbo_tblPatCountryApplication.InvId,
    'Add', dbo_tblpatinvention.disclosurestatus, ...
FROM 
    dbo_tblPatInvention 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo_tblPatCountryApplication ON dbo_tblPatInvention.InvId = dbo_tblPatCountryApplication.InvId
ORDER BY 
    dbo_tblpatcountryapplication.invid;
```

I'd like to execute the above statement so that the results are dumped into a new table. Can anyone please advise how to embed the statement into a subquery that will play nicely with a `SELECT INTO`?

Comment: Do you know what the INSERT in sql does?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add an [`INTO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) clause to your existing query to create a new table filled with the results of the query:

```
SELECT ...
INTO MyNewStagingTable -- Creates a new table with the results of this query
FROM MyOtherTable
    JOIN ...
```

However, you will have to make sure each column has a name, as in:

```
SELECT dbo_tblPatCountryApplication.AppId, -- Cool, already has a name
    '' AS Column2, -- Given a name to create that new table with select...into
    ...
INTO MyNewStagingTable
FROM dbo_tblPatInvention INNER JOIN ...
```

Also, you might like to use [aliases for your tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455.aspx), too, to make code a little more readable;

```
SELECT a.AppId,
    '' AS Column2,
    ...
INTO MyNewStagingTable
FROM dbo_tblPatInvention AS i
    INNER JOIN dbo_tblPatCountryApplication AS a ON i.InvId = a.InvId
ORDER BY a.InvId
```

One last note is that it looks odd to have named your tables `dbo_tblXXX` as dbo is normally the schema name and is separated from the table name with dot notation, e.g. `dbo.tblXXX`. I'm assuming that you already have a fully working select query before adding the into clause. Some also consider using Hungarian notation in your database (tblName) to be a type of anti-pattern to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
INSERT INTO stagingtable (AppId, ...)
SELECT ... --your select goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

If the staging table doesn't exist and you want to create it on insert then try the following:

```
SELECT dbo_tblPatCountryApplication.AppId,'', dbo_tblPatCountryApplication.InvId,
       'Add', dbo_tblpatinvention.disclosurestatus .......
INTO StagingTable
FROM dbo_tblPatInvention 
INNER JOIN dbo_tblPatCountryApplication 
              ON dbo_tblPatInvention.InvId = dbo_tblPatCountryApplication.InvId;
```

If you want to insert them in a specific order then use try using a sub-query in the from clause:

```
SELECT *
INTO StagingTable
FROM 
(
   SELECT dbo_tblPatCountryApplication.AppId, '', dbo_tblPatCountryApplication.InvId, 
          'Add', dbo_tblpatinvention.disclosurestatus .......
   FROM dbo_tblPatInvention 
   INNER JOIN dbo_tblPatCountryApplication ON 
              dbo_tblPatInvention.InvId = dbo_tblPatCountryApplication.InvId
    order by dbo_tblpatcountryapplication.invid
) a;
```